# If you do not use the SIZEOF_HEADER built-in function in the LD link script, the size of the executable file changes, why?

Tags: linux, x86, ld, linker-scripts

github:https://github.com/Amyassient/link_test/tree/main

eg:Use LD 2.28 whenever possible
source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){     
 printf("hello world");
 return 0;
}
```

not use SIZEOF_HEADERS:

```
PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000));
**. = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000);**
.interp         : { *(.interp) }
.note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
.hash           : { *(.hash) }
.gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
.dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
.dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
.gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
.gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
.gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
```

The file size：

```
chang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/study/linker_test$ ls -al a.out 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chang chang **2098312** Apr 11 13:54 a.out
```

There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x201970:
Section Headers:

```
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
   Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
   0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
[ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400000  00200000
   000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
[ 2] .note.gnu.propert NOTE             0000000000400020  00200020
   00000000000000e0  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
[ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400100  00200100
```

use SIZEOF_HEADERS:

```
PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000));
**. = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;**
.interp         : { *(.interp) }
.note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
.hash           : { *(.hash) }
.gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
.dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
.dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
.gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
.gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
.gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
```

The file size：

```
chang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/study/linker_test$ ls -al a.out 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chang chang **1392** Apr 11 14:34 a.out
```

There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1938:

Section Headers:

```
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
   Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
   0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
[ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000270  00000270
   000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
[ 2] .note.gnu.propert NOTE             0000000000000290  00000290
```

The file size has obviously changed. Why?

Comment: What's the architecture this linker script is for?

Comment: Which is the default or normal linker script?

Comment: the architecture is elfx86_64, the second link script is default link script(use SIZEOF_HEADERS)

Comment: Does the resulting executable work?  `1392` bytes is vastly smaller than 2 MiB, so is the big one full of padding or did the small one leave out any sections?  (i.e. what are you linking?  A decent-size project or a trivial hello world?)

Comment: Can you provide the full program and linker script for us to play with? (assuming it's small, or on github or something)

Comment: What exactly does padding mean? Why padding